# "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: google-gax" when testing Google Street View Publish API

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, pkg-resources, google-streetview-publish

I am testing the Google Street View Publish API so I installed the library [gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1](https://pypi.org/project/gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1/) and then I tried running the [Python code](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/libraries) example to upload a photo.

In the line:

`from google.streetview.publish.v1 import street_view_publish_service_client as client`

the code raises an error:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: google-gax

According to my package list, google-gax==0.15.16 is included in the installation of gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1. I have tried updating to 0.16.0 but it doesn't work either.

Any hint to fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
pip freeze

cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
dill==0.2.8.1
enum34==1.1.6
future==0.16.0
futures==3.2.0
gapic-google-maps-streetview-publish-v1==0.1.4
google-auth==1.5.0
google-gax==0.15.16
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
grpcio==1.12.1
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.7
oauth2client==3.0.0
ply==3.8
proto-google-maps-streetview-publish-v1==0.1.4
protobuf==3.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.3
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pyreadline==2.1
requests==2.19.1
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.23
```

Comment: Can you provide your pip commands? or requirements.txt file? How are you doing dependencies installation?

Comment: @J.LValtueña question is edited with my `pip freeze`. I have created a virtualenv and just installed `gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1` after a clean installation. Still raising the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this before and I used

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1
```

it's worth a try. Hope this helps

Comment: That is the solution I have tried from the beginning. I even did a clean uninstall/reinstall of Python 2.7.15 and the Google Cloud SDK and still getting the same issue...

Comment: @Finfa811 I added my pip freeze below. We have the same one except for pyreadline (i don't have one). Also when I installed my python pip, i just used `sudo easy_install pip`.

Comment: `pyreadline`is a readline API on Windows, I don't think it makes any difference

Comment: Are you able to work with the Street View Publish API then?

Comment: @Finfa811 yes, I'm able to work on it. I don't understand why you're having errors. I too used the python code example.

Comment: I have found the solution. The Google App Engine was causing conflicts with the code because it includes a very old version of `setuptools` in the distribution. Just need to disable GAE support to make the test code work. I opened a new [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5527) in Github regarding the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like google-gax is deprecated (https://pypi.org/project/google-gax/) it has been wholly replaced by google-api-core (https://pypi.org/project/google-api-core/).

Comment: I see, but `google-gax` is automatically installed with the `gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1` package. And it is called in `street_view_publish_service_client.py`, in the line `from google.gax import api_callable`. 
So if `google-gax` is deprecated, there is no way to use the Street View Publish API until a new version is deployed, isn't there?